# openai.error.APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI

Tags: python, asynchronous, embedding, openai-api, chatgpt-api

when my project run this code it will return
`openai.error.APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI`

```
async def embeddings_acreate(input: list[str]):
    
    return await openai.Embedding.acreate(
        api_key=await get_openai_api_key(),
        model='text-embedding-ada-002',
        input=input,
        timeout=60,
    )
```

but if I tried:

```
import openai
import logging


openai.api_key = 'secret'

input_list = [
    "tell me your name"
]

response = openai.Embedding.create(
    model="text-embedding-ada-002",
    input=input_list
)

embeddings = response["data"]
print(embeddings)
```

it worked......

I hope to use async and make it

Answer (score 10):

Faced the same issue. Apparently it is a mac specific issue which is discussed here: https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/issues/627

Basically you have to run the following command

```
bash /Applications/Python*/Install\ Certificates.command
```

Or just double click *Certificates.command* file in /*Applications/Python*/* folder on your mac. Hope this helps.

Comment: Omg, after 3 hours of searching finally something that solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: But I use mini conda and there is no Python* in /Applications

Comment: cannot thank you enough for this answer!!

Answer (score 1):

I hit this errror when I was running behind a VPN (Proton VPN), I disabled the VPN and issue went away.

```
APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

Comment: Same issue with ProtonVPN on Windows... weirdly it worked fine for small prompts but not larger...

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue.

My situation:

- windows
- intranet with proxy

try to:

- setting\env add 「OPENAI_PROXY:http://user:password@proxy server ip:port」
- restart system(important!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Rahul Sankrutyan's answer, for those who have virtual environments installed such as conda, pyenv and etc. It should not only work on MacOS but also on Linux/Windows.

- activate your virtual env
- run script at  https://gist.github.com/marschhuynh/31c9375fc34a3e20c2d3b9eb8131d8f3 (I folked at https://gist.github.com/samuelchen/d2e0f74d344a24001a9409eaee4b9d09)

it will update `certifi` package and find your certificates in virtual env then update the certificates.